# Netplan does nothing

Tags: netplan, static-ip

I have this config

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.103/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Then I do: `sudo netplan try` and press ENTER
And finally I `sudo reboot` or `shutdown` and start manually

And when the machine comes back up the ip is always `192.168.0.102`

What would be the problem?

#### System info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Server
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

- I `systemd-networkd` is running:

```
 systemd-networkd.service - Network Service                                                                                                                                                                       
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)                                                                                                                
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-08-09 06:29:26 UTC; 21min ago                                                                                                                                         
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket                                                                                                                                                                             
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)                                                                                                                                                                       
   Main PID: 1307 (systemd-network)                                                                                                                                                                                
     Status: "Processing requests..."                                                                                                                                                                              
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38110)                                                                                                                                                                                      
     Memory: 1.7M                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service                                                                                                                                                                
             └─1307 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added my system info. I have tried with both networkd and without

Comment: It is Ubuntu server

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: `Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found` is not running probably

Comment: `systemd-networkd` is running

Comment: Thanks anyway  !

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I was running with automated bridge setup from this blog post: https://octetz.com/docs/2020/2020-11-13-vm-networks/

So my network config was coming from networkd /etc/systemd/network/2-br0-dhcp.network:

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

So I have just changed this to:

```
[Match]                                                                                                  
Name=br0                                                                                                 
                                                                                                         
[Network]                                                                                                
DHCP=no                                                                                                  
Address=192.168.0.103/24                                                                                 
Gateway=192.168.0.1                                                                                      
DNS=1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Note that it's quite possible to configure your bridge using netplan.  In any case, it's a good idea to pick one layer/tool and apply all your network config there, whether it's netplan or networkd.

Comment: Yea, I just forgot that it was configured that way